# Get names of properties which are not null

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reflection

I get the properties of some object

```
var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties()
                          .Select(x => x.Name)
                          .ToList()
```

How can I get names of the properties, which values are not `null`?

And how can I get those?

Comment: add x.GetValue(<yourObject>, null) != null as a where clause.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this code for C# 7:

```
public static void GetProps<T>(T obj)
{
    var result = typeof(T).GetProperties()
        .Select(x => new { property = x.Name, value = x.GetValue(obj) })
        .Where(x => x.value != null)
        .ToList();
}
```

Or you can create a `Tuple` for older C# version:

```
public static void GetProps<T>(T obj)
{
    var result = typeof(T).GetProperties()                  
        .Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.Name, x.GetValue(obj)))
        .Where(x => x.Item2 != null)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: @George Alexandria as far I know anonymous types were introduced in c# 4 (or 5? I'm not sure). However thank you for `Tuple` version )

Comment: @ Yes, it's my mistake) [They were introduced in c# 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_type)